Accounting for bandwidth in spectrum data
I'm looking at the USGS Spectral Library, and spectra are represented with the center wavelength, bandwidth, and amplitude value for each channel. I assume that a wider bandwidth will result in larger recorded amplitude for a given channel, as a large fraction of photons will be able to activate the sensor. But, what's not clear to me is:

How do you normalize the samples to control for the effects of bandwidth and get amplitudes that can be meaningfully compared?
Has this already been done in the recorded data, or will I need to normalize the channels in or to be able to render a spectrum plot?

